# Difference b/w using i<strlen() and str[i] != '\0'

Tags: arrays, c, string, algorithm, runtimeexception

When I use `for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)` then I am getting **time limit exceed** error. And When I use `for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)` my code get **successful** submit. Why?

I am also providing link of question from codechef - https://www.codechef.com/problems/LCPESY

Type 1:

```
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++) {
        f1[s1[i]]++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s2); i++) {
        f2[s2[i]]++;
    }
```

Type 2:

```
    for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        f1[s1[i]]++;
    }
    for (i = 0; s2[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        f2[s2[i]]++;
    }
```

Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long int min(long int a, long int b) {
    if (a >= b)
        return b;
    else
        return a;
}

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        char s1[10001], s2[10001];
        scanf("%s%s", s1, s2);
        long int f1[200] = { 0 }, f2[200] = { 0 }, i, count = 0;
    
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++) {
            f1[s1[i]]++;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(s2); i++) {
            f2[s2[i]]++;
        }
        
        for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            count += min(f1[i], f2[i]);
        }
        printf("%ld\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `strlen` is implemented as a loop that looks like the loop in "Type-2". So if the string has 100 characters, "Type-2" compares 100 characters before it finds the `\0`, but "Type-1" compares 10000 characters looking for the `\0` 100 times. To fix "Type-1", you should call `strlen` **once** before the loop, and save the length in a variable.

Comment: `strlen()` is evaluated once for every time through the loop; a smart compiler could perhps move the function out of the loop ... but maybe if you try `unsigned limit = strlen(s); for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) { ... }` it will get accepted.

Comment: The two loops are not necessarily equivalent, if for example `s` gets modified inside the loop.

Comment: @pmg Thanks. I have tried your method and it works. But why strlen() evaluated every time through loop I didn't understand.

Comment: A `for` loop is basically composed of 4 parts: the initialization, the condition, the increment, and the body (`for (<increment>; <condition>; <increment>) { <body> }`). Except for `<initialization>` which only exectutes once, all parts execute once each time "the `for` executes" and the `strlen()` in question is part of the `<condition>` statement .. ie the `for` loop runs like this: `<initialization>`/`<condition>`/`<body>`/`<increment>`/`<condition>`/`<body>`/`<increment>`/`<condition>`/`<body>`/`<increment>`/`...`/`<condition>`

Answer (score 5):

If a non-optimizing compiler is used it can be that `strlen` is re-evaluated once per each iteration. `strlen` then needs to check each and every character in the string for equivalence with `0`. This results in **quadratic runtime**, where there are `O(n²)` checks for the terminatin null instead of just the necessary `O(n)` times. In the `strlen` code the timeout happens because it does perhaps 2,000,000 null checks and 10,000 other operations; the other code would do 2,000 null checks and those same 10,000 other operations and not time out.

---

However, this need not be a case. Due to the *as-if* rule, a C compiler can generate **exactly** equivalent machine  for the cases

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++){
    f1[s1[i]] ++;
}
```

and

```
for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    f1[s1[i]] ++;
}
```

because a compiler can easily prove that the inner loop cannot possibly change `s1` and therefore both forms would behave equivalently.

Comment: Good answer.  Deeper: It only takes a slightly more complex code for the compiler to **not** be able to readily make the `i < strlen(s1)` is the same as `s1[i] != '\0'`.  Hence `s1[i] != '\0'` or `s1[i]` is, IMO, preferred and more idiomatic C.

Comment: I think "idiomatic" C would be `for (char cp* const = s1; *cp; ++cp) f1[*cp]++; ` instead of using an index. It's certainly what I would write (except that I would use `unsigned char` to avoid possible negative indexes to `f1`).

Comment: @rici Pedantic: Your use of `unsigned char` is especially a good idea for dinosaur non-2's complement signed `char` machines.   `for (char cp*  = s1; *cp; ++cp)` incorrectly stops on -0, whereas `for (unsigned char cp*  = s1; *cp; ++cp)` is correct.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63000807/2410359) good answer:`

> Difference b/w using `i<strlen()` and `str[i] != '\0'`

Code like `int i; ... i < strlen(s1)` readily complains about mismatched sign-ness - when such warnings are enabled. *Usually* inoffensive code like that discourages wide use of that warning.  I see that as a less preferred approach.  `str[i] != '\0'` does not cause that warning.

---

Some other concerns

**Prevent buffer overflow**

```
char s1[10001], s2[10001];
// scanf("%s%s", s1, s2);
if (scanf("%10000s%10000s", s1, s2) == 2)  {
  // OK, success, lets go!
```

**There are more than 200 characters.**

```
    // long int f1[200] = { 0 };
    long int f1[256] = { 0 };
    // or better
    long int f1[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { 0 };
```

**Avoid a negative index**

```
        // f1[s1[i]]++;
        f1[(unsigned char) s1[i]]++;
```

or use unquestionable unsigned types.

```
        // char s1[10001];
        unsigned char s1[10001];
```